# Validate an email address

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I check that a user's email address ends in on of the three

**@camel.com, @mel.com, @camelofegypt.com**

This is my code so far, it just validates whether or not the user has provided any text

```
if ($.trim($("#email").val()).length === 0) {
alert('You must provide valid input');
return false;
```

I want to implement the email address validation into my code.

Comment: Use a regex. anything followed by @camel.com or the others.

Comment: What about the email address: `"David SkyMesh" <foo@camel.com>` ?

Comment: Refer this http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2011/04/validate-email-address-using-jquery.html

Comment: `^.*@.*mel.*\.com$` , if you are sure that the string contains only one email address. and there are no other domains which contains `mel` string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the [library to regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html), it is difficult to truly validate an email address.  However, the below taken from the above website will do a good job.

> The official standard is known as RFC 2822. It describes the syntax that valid email addresses must adhere to. You can (but you shouldn't--read on) implement it with this regular expression:

```
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
```

Simple Regex:

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b
```

**Trade offs of validating email addresses:**

> Yes, there are a whole bunch of email addresses that my pet regex doesn't match. The most frequently quoted example are addresses on the .museum top level domain, which is longer than the 4 letters my regex allows for the top level domain. I accept this trade-off because the number of people using .museum email addresses is extremely low. I've never had a complaint that the order forms or newsletter subscription forms on the JGsoft websites refused a .museum address (which they would, since they use the above regex to validate the email address).

However, if you just want your specific domain this is definitely a possibility but it is not recommended to deny an email address because it fails these regular expressions.

### **Taking the above you could simply validate using the following Regex:**

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@(camel|mel|camelofegypt)\.com\b
```

***or:***

```
^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@(camel|mel|camelofegypt)\.com$
```

The difference between these two regex are simple, the first regex will match an email address contained within a longer string.  While the second regular expression will only match if the whole string is the email address.

***JavaScript Regex:***

```
/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@(camel|mel|camelofegypt)\.com\b/i
```

***or:***

```
/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@(camel|mel|camelofegypt)\.com$/i
```

*Special Note: You should likely allow for case insensitive with your regex using the `i` parameter since `John@CAMEL.com` is the same as `john@camel.com`.  Which i've done in the above regex.*

Answer (score 3):

use the following regex:

```
var reg=/@(camel|mel|camelofegypt)\.com$/
 reg.test(email)
```

This only validates if you email ends in one of the three above. If you want ot know general email validation, search the web. There are tons of those

Comment: more the .com to outside the grouping, it doesn't need to be repeated.  Also you should check for valid characters before the `@` symbol.

Answer (score 1):

```
function ValidateEmail(email) {
 var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  return regex.test(email);
}
```

**OR**

This is a regular-expression email validation comparison that will test a bunch of valid/invalid email address against the regex provided by you in the textarea below.

```
^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this javascript

```
function IsEmail(email) {
 var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  return regex.test(email);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function,

```
 function validateEmail($email) {
  var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
  if( !emailReg.test( $email ) ) {
   return false;
 } else {
  return true;
}
}


if( !validateEmail(email)) { /* do stuff here */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x=$("#email").val();
var n=x.split("@");
if($.inArray(camel.com,n)!= -1)//checks if camel.com is there in your email address if not  the value will be -1 @is not given in front of camel.com because its split after @ which means that @will be present before it if camel.com is prescent.
  {
}                                   
else
if($.inArray(mel.com,n)!= -1)
{}
else
 if($.inArray(camelofegypth.com,n)!= -1)
{}
else
   alert("");
```

Answer (score 0):

using new regex

demo [Here](http://goo.gl/BPZXE)

added support for [Address tags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Address_tags) (+ sign)

```
function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
return pattern.test(emailAddress);
};
```

> Note : [Keep in mind that no 100%  regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)  email check exists